# Ler página com chamada assíncrona

Tags: javascript, c#, webrequest

Faço uma chamada via `WebRequest` e essa página tem uma função JavaScript que o resultado dela não consigo recuperar (ela carrega uma imagem). Eu preciso esperar terminar o carregamento da página para depois que a página for totalmente carregada, e eu conseguo carregar toda a página?

Abaixo o código:

```
            WebRequest request = webRequest.Create("http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/aplicacoes/atcta/cpf/consultapublica.asp");
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Comment: tem o código dela ?

Comment: **Enzo Tiezzi**, incluí o código na pergunta.

Comment: esse `responseFromServer` ta vindo algo ?

Comment: caso seja uma imagem mesmo, vai ter que usar um vetor de bytes pra isso

Comment: Sim. Vem sim Vem todo o conteúdo. Acontece, que no final do carregamento da página, ele chama uma função javascript, e essa função insere uma imagem dentro de uma div determinada. Porém como ele chama no final do carregamento, o request não trás essa imagem entendeu? Eu precisaria de uma forma que ele só carregasse a página depois de alguns segundos, onde eu sei que ele já teria rodado a função de carregamento da imagem, entende?

Comment: na parte do javascript, como está o código? vc realmente tem que dar um tempo enquanto ele traz a informação, mas vamos ver como está fazendo, pra saber a melhor maneira de fazer isso

Comment: essa documentação explica muito bem como seu problema pode ser resolvido também, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: O que notei é que você não está fazendo de forma assíncrona ainda. Certo? E você sabe que está forma de fazer pode ser problemática se der algum erro no meio do processo? Regra geral é que você nunca chama qualquer `close` em C#. O código deve ser montado para garantir que ele sempre seja chamado pelo compilador.

Comment: Não, mas se eu fizer de forma assíncrona, eu consigo o que preciso? Você sabe como faço isso @bigown ?

Comment: Parece que o melhor aí é você usar o WebBrowser, e seus eventos, para renderizar esta página e interagir com o conteúdo HTML. Eles já colocaram este captcha para dificultar o acesso automatizado às páginas. Um retrocesso.

Comment: Dê uma olhada: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207730/how-to-make-ordinary-webrequest-async-and-awaitable. Não sei se entendi bem o que voc~e quer com essa parte do JS.